# makefile executes non-existing commands before it exits

Tags: makefile

I have a `makefile` with a default target `all`. The target itself is irrelevant, but **at its very end** I have an `@echo "done"` command. Is there
any scenario that `makefile` will execute something **after** it echoes `done`? In my case some intermediate files are being `rm`-ed and I have no idea where that came from since my `makefile` has no `rm` commands at all (!). My `makefile` is too big to post and I can not reproduce this phenomenon when I synthesize a smaller one. Any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my makefile call rm on dependencies after building?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29114215/why-does-my-makefile-call-rm-on-dependencies-after-building)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an empty `.SECONDARY:` rule, to prevent this default behavior.